# Using libcurl to list IMAP Inbox

Tags: email, curl, imap

I'm running Xubuntu 13.04 and have the newest version of libcurl/curl installed:

> $ curl -V
>
> curl 7.29.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 librtmp/2.3

Using the following command I tried to list the mails in my Inbox

> curl -u 'user:password' -X "EXAMINE INBOX" --url 'imaps://mymailserver.com:993/INBOX'

But instead I get only the body(text) of my first(oldest) email in the inbox. I tried some other commands as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267500/libcurl-and-imap). But every command returns the text body of my first mail. The same happens when I run the query via libcurl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl has only limited support for IMAP until version 7.30. I have updated to 7.33 and now everything works fine. 
I got the answer on the [curl mailing list](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-12/0022.html).